# How to politely reply to someone who applied for a job on behalf of someone else?

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, ethics

So our company had a vacancy for a Senior Finance and Admin Officer. All applications came to my email. One person applied on behalf of someone else. It's the first time I've come across something like this. I think it's unethical and it just tells me that the person who is looking for a job is lazy.

How do I reply to the person who sent the application?

Comment: The *polite* thing to do would not be to make assumptions about the applicant, but as you've already done that...

Comment: Were they a recruiter?  An admin assistant?  We need a bit more information to help.  What do you want to accomplish here?  Reject the candidate?  Shame the candidate? Cause unnecessary drama?

Comment: "One person applied on behalf of someone else." Did they have permission to apply on behalf of that person? Are they hoping to get a commission? Does your company have a policy against 3rd party intermediaries? If you do, you could just say: "Sorry, no 3rd party intermediaries. Candidates must apply directly, or not at all." You may want to consult with your HR to see what the official policy is, if any.

Comment: My first thought was why does A apply on behalf of B, what is it about and what would they expect? So why not ask exactly that?

Answer (score 11):

How did they apply for them?  Did that person give them their resume rather than fill out the form online?  That's a fairly common technique, and how many companies do referrals.  I would never apply to a company if I knew someone working there-  I'd talk to them and have them refer me (they usually even get a bonus for doing so if I'm hired).  You can ask them to fill out things the normal way, but don't hold that against them.

Or did the person just apply for the other without telling them?  Inform them that the person needs to apply himself.  But again I wouldn't hold it against them, they may not even know the person did it.

Its not a problem to want them to work via your usual channels.  But you're putting a lot of assumptions on the person who was applied for that aren't warranted.

Comment: I don't know what the problem would be applying for a company where someone you know also works. This could be a cultural thing. Do you know anything about OP's culture?

Comment: @OmarL You're misinterpreting the answer - it's saying "I wouldn't apply *via normal means* if I knew someone that worked there" but instead that the application would be done via an internal referral.

Answer (score 3):

You left out A LOT of important information?

WHO did apply for who? Mother for their son? Husband for his wife? Headhunter for a client?
I never applied for a Job in my life, my headhunter is doing all the work.

WHY did that person apply for them? Maybe the person was incapable to do so? Maybe they were just afraid? Perhabs they arent very good at writing?

HOW did they apply? And how do you know it wasnt them?

Tell them to reapply if it really is that bad. Or if that person isnt a fit anyways just handle it like you would if they applied for themself.

I mean I can understand that if the 70 y.o. mother applies for her 40 y.o. son that it is strange. Then you can just use the same phrase you use for all applicants that you refuse and maybe a nice info that recruiter appreciate if a candidate applies for themselves.